# Renci.SshNet ShellStream seems to be dropping characters

Tags: vb.net, ssh, streaming

After some google, I have not found an answer that matches my exact situation. This maybe more info than you care, but I think I need to set the stage for my question. My simple goal is to read and command a Cisco IOS device either with serial console or ssh. To abstract the "business logic" from the transport I was looking at building a stream. For the serial console, after creating a serial port, I use the basestream and all works well. FYI this was my rosetta like moment for getting the serial port streaming working. [If you *must* use .NET System.IO.Ports.SerialPort](http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport) Adding the ssh stream (for me) research took me to Sharps and Renci for my ssh connection.I decided to try Renci first. Downloaded and compiled to get my dll (my project is in VB.NET). Connected, created a shell stream, then passed that stream to the same functions that the serial stream used. Everything works except when I do a "show run". I have my terminal length set to 0 so there is no page breaks. I do get output, but when I am using the ssh there are missing parts in the capture. My theory is at the serial speed (9600 baud) the stream is able to keep up, but at lan speed (1 gig bit) I am overrunning the buffer. What is actually captured is a little different, but mostly around the same area text is missing. Small screen grabs such as "show ip int br" works great. I have increased the "CreateShellStream" buffer size without any change. I started looking at the Renci code, if I am understanding it correctly, it does not seem to pass buffer size to anything. 
Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I had a friend who says, we all server as an example, some of us good, some bad. I have to fall on the sword and be an bad example.
First the bottom line is my buffer that the streaming call back added to and my higher level read functions that parsed that buffer. **I was not protecting it with a synclock.**